# Pygtk Adjustment & Vertical Scale: How to invert curser max/min

Tags: python, gtk, adjustment

I have translated this [code](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?tut-gtk2-numtxt-hvscales) to python 2.7, it's working.
But now I have a problem I can't solve by myself:
I would like to have the 100 value on the top, and 0 on the down. How to do this?

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf8

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Fan():
  def destroy(self, widget, donnees=None):
    gtk.main_quit()
    exit()

  def __init__(self):
    window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    window.set_title('Vertical Scales')
    window.set_border_width(10)
    window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)
    window.set_size_request(-1, 150)

    # Récupération des informations de surface d'affichage
    self.screen = window.get_screen()
    self.largeur = int(self.screen.get_width())
    self.hauteur = int(self.screen.get_height())

    window.move(self.largeur/2-150,self.hauteur/2-40)
    window.set_default_size(100, 200)

    #Adjustments
                      #value, min, max, step, pg-incr,pg-size
    adj1 = gtk.Adjustment(50, 0, 100, 1.0,  1.0,    0.0)
    adj2 = gtk.Adjustment(50, 0, 100, 1.0,  1.0,    0.0)

    scale1 = gtk.VScale(adj1)
    scale2 = gtk.VScale(adj2)

    scale1.value_pos = gtk.POS_RIGHT
    scale2.value_pos = gtk.POS_LEFT

    hbox = gtk.HBox(True, 5)
    hbox.pack_start_defaults(scale1)
    hbox.pack_start_defaults(scale2)

    window.add(hbox)
    hbox.show()
    window.show_all()

if __name__ == "__main__":

  base = Fan()
  gtk.main()
```

Here is a screenshot, I would like to have 100 with the curser on the top, and 0 with the curseur on the bottom of the window:

[image: gtk.Adjutment example]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gtk.Scale objects inherit from [gtk.Range](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkrange.html#method-gtkrange--set-inverted); you need to set the Range property "inverted" to True.

So put this somewhere after the statements that create your VScales:

```
scale1.set_inverted(True)
scale2.set_inverted(True)
```

---

PS. To run your code on my system I had to change your coding statement to

`# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`

but I *think* that's because of changes the Stackoverflow formatting software does to text posted here.

---

The official GTK+ tutorials are good (although they contain some examples that use deprecated code) but GTK is so big that it's not easy for the tutorials to cover everything. You need to get familiar with the GTK reference manual, and how it <s>hides</s> explains things. :)

So if you look at the page for gtk.HScale, it has a link to various properties, including gtk.Range properties. That link mentions "inverted" as one of the properties, and elsewhere on the page it explicitly describes the `set_inverted` and `get_inverted` methods. Note that functions named like that are standard in GTK for setting & getting properties, so if you know (or can guess :) ) a property name, then you also know how to set or get it.

The gtk.HScale page also mentions that it inherits from gtk.Scale, so that page is also worth looking at for extra info.

---

I just noticed that you have

```
self.largeur = int(self.screen.get_width())
self.hauteur = int(self.screen.get_height())
```

But you can just do

```
self.largeur = self.screen.get_width()
self.hauteur = self.screen.get_height()
```

since those get_width() & get_height() methods both return `int`.

Rather than using window.move(), you should take a look at `gtk.Window.set_position()` and the [GTK Window Position Constants](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/gtk-constants.html#gtk-window-position-constants).

Comment: Thanks a lot, because no tutorial explain this!

Comment: PS: Both works on my machine. I don't know realy why, because I tried to copy/paste the code in a new file, and it's working too..
Edit: I'm french, using a Kubuntu x64 system.

Comment: Ok, I noticed your explainations for `gtk.Window.set_position()`. I will watch it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I kinda guessed you're French :) (FWIW, I studied French in high school, but that was several decades ago...). I'm also using a KDE distro, Mepis 11, which is vaguely related to the Ubuntu family (they both are descendants of Knoppix), on an old 32 bit machine. I'm using kate as my editor. My default locale is en_AU.utf8, but I generally don't play with the encoding setting in kate...

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance. GTK is fun, although it does get a bit frustrating at times trying to wade through all the information in the reference manual. But it's _so_ satisfying when you find the info you need, and get your program looking and working the way you want it to.

Comment: Yes, coding in python is an hobby for me, and PyGTK is the most easy langage I have found. I can do almost what I want! :)
Have fun in Australia !! :)